# About threads and condition variable and synchronise

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, pthreads

i am trying to understand the condition variables in thread programming can anyone explain how it works with the mutex and what are the condition variable so it can synchronise threads??
condition variables and threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Here I am using 3 mutexs and 3 condition variables. With the below examples you can schedule or control any number of threads in C. First look at the first thread below. Here it locked mutex lock1  (so that other thread could not access the codes) starts executing (codes not added just comments) and  finally after completing its task waiting on cond1, likewise second thread locked mutex lock2, starts executing  its business logic  and finally waits on condition cond2 and 3rd thread locked mutex lock3, starts executing its business logic and finally waits on condition cond3. I am not adding any business logic here because this is just an example. In the commented section you can add your business logic which will execute  in parallel mode. Suppose thread3 depends on final output of thread1 which is going to be inserted in a table and thread3 will read that information before creating it final result and thread2 depends on final outcome of thread3 to generate its final outcome. Hence thread1 after inserting the data into table, signals thread3 through condition variable to go ahead with its final process. That means thread1 controls thread3. As thread2 depends on final outcome from thread3, hence thread3  controls  the execution of Thread2. Here we can allow thread1 to execute independently as its operation does not depends on any other thread, but for example of thread control we are controlling all the threads here and hence thread1 is being controlled from thread2.

To start the controlling process, we are releasing thread1 first. In the main thread (i.e. main function, every program has one main thread, in C/C++ this main thread is created automatically by operating system once the control pass to the main method/function by kernel) we are calling pthread_cond_signal(&cond1); Once this function called from main thread,  thread1 which was waiting on cond1 will be released and it will start executing further. Once it finishes  with its final task, it will call pthread_cond_signal(&cond3); now thread which was waiting on condition cond3 i.e. thread3 will be released and it will start to execute it’s final stage and will call pthread_cond_signal(&cond2); and it will release the thread which is waiting on condition cond2 i.e. in this case thread2. This is the way we can schedule and control execution of thread in multi-threaded environment.

```
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond3 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock3 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int TRUE = 1;

void * threadMethod1(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread1\n");
  do{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    //Add your business logic(parallel execution codes)  here
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
    printf("I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table \n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);/* Now allow 3rd thread to process */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod2(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread2\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);
    //Add your business logic(parallel execution codes)  here
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &lock2);
    printf("I am thread2  generating the final report and inserting into a table \n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod3(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread3\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock3);
    //Add your business logic(parallel execution codes)  here
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond3, &lock3);
    printf("I am thread3  generating the final report and inserting into a table \n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock3);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Before creating the threads\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadMethod1, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread1\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, threadMethod2, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread2\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, threadMethod3, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread3\n");
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);/* Now allow first thread to process first */


  sleep(1);
  TRUE = 0;/* Stop all the thread */
  sleep(3);

 /* this is how we join thread before exit from a system */
  /*  
  pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid3,NULL);*/

 exit(0);
}
```

Comment: can this method applied in a "n" thread program for synchronisation ???